# Use of std::use_facet to get local currency

Tags: c++, std

I am trying to use the standard library to decide billing info based on locale. I went through a few examples http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/use_facet

As per the example it returns USD but when I run I  am get nothing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc = std::locale(""); // user's preferred locale
    std::cout << "Your currency string is "
              << std::use_facet<std::moneypunct<char, true>>(loc).curr_symbol() << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
Your currency string is 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Expected output (if user from US)

```
Your currency string is USD 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Expected output (if user from India )

```
Your currency string is RS  
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Am I Missing anything? How to make it to use by default use the locale  based on time zone of the user?

Comment: FWIW, I get `AUD` when I run that code (luckily, I'm in Australia). Perhaps the Americans (and apologies in advance to everyone in the set of `America and not (USA)`) think they're so important they don't *need* a currency indicator, it should be the default. You know, like the TLDs. :-)

Comment: In any case, you'd be well advised to add your environment details to the question (OS, compiler, versions, etc). If it's an issue with a *specific* tool, that will assist greatly, if only to let us know we should avoid it :-)

Comment: I live in the USA and am using clang on macOS.  I get `USD`.  This is highly platform-specific.  The standard doesn't even say what `locale("")` means, only that it exists.  I wish locale was better supported in C++, with standardized names for locales and what clients could expect from those named locales.

Comment: Thank you guys I am using xcode , still not able to figure out what needs to be set

Answer (score 0):

Got some break through

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>


int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "it_IT");
    const struct lconv * const currentlocale = localeconv();
    std::cout<<"In the current locale, the default currency symbol is:"<<currentlocale->currency_symbol<<std::endl;

}
```

Output

In the current locale, the default currency symbol is:Eu

Program ended with exit code: 0